# getDestinationGeographicPoint() in geotools returns wrong coordinates in South/West

Tags: java, geotools

I am trying to calculate a coordinate given an azimuth, distance and start point.
If my code uses an start coordinate in North/East quadrant, all goes fine.
But, by using 0,0 coordinates, an azimuth -90 or 180 give me an inverted result movement.

Here is my sample code:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
GeodeticCalculator calc = new GeodeticCalculator( crs );

calc.setStartingGeographicPoint(0, 0); // Starting from Lon/Lat 0,0
calc.setDirection( -90, 2000 );

Point2D dest = calc.getDestinationGeographicPoint();

System.out.println(calc);
System.out.println( dest.getX() + " " + dest.getY() );
```

This is the output:

```
Coordinate Reference System:  WGS 84             
Ellipsoid:                    WGS 84             
Source point:                 00°00,0'E 00°00,0'N
Target point:                 00°01,0'W 00°00,0'N
Azimuth:                      -90°00,0'          
Orthodromic distance:         2000 m             

-0.017966305682390427 1.107533167043945E-18
```

I'm using this site http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ to show the points.
As you can see, a movement in azimuth -90 ( to west ) results in West coordinate of target be grow (`Target point: 00°01,0'W 00°00,0'N`) but the numeric representation (degrees) is not correct ( the second argument is the latitude and MUST be ZERO and not 1.107533167043945E-18, since my movement was to WEST).

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Here is my goal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917340/geotools-how-to-do-dead-reckoning-and-course-calculations-using-geotools-class

Comment: The latitude value *is* zero when dealing with double precision.

Comment: try formatting the output to 3(?) decimal places

Comment: @iant : ok, and then, when I move for 10.000 Km to west? I can't touch the returned value. I'ts comming incorrect from getDestinationGeographicPoint() function. If you put this values in a map, you can see "Target point" tell me I've moved 2Km to west (correct), and 1.107533167043945E-18, in latiude tell me I've moved miles and miles to NORTH ! Please pay attention to question. This function itself is not coherent with internal object data.

Comment: @mkennedy the precision is not concerning here. If the internal object data tells me `00°01,0'W 00°00,0'N` then the latitude will NEVER be `1.107533167043945E-18`. Go to a map and see the deference between zero and 1.107 in coordinates! Can you trust your GPS with this diference?

Comment: @MagnoC 1.107533167043945E-18 = 0.0000000000000000001107 - It is 0 for all practical purposes, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison

Comment: @iant I understood you, but this function already returns a java double primitive. Should I round it in every case?. I can't format to 3 decimal places without loosing the needed coordinates precision. I can't understand how to deal with. By the way, thanks for your patience.

Comment: I can't understand the issue you have? The answer is correct.

Comment: but there is no actual answer :-) The code you posted is working fine and I can't work out what you are asking.

Comment: Yep! My mistake. I'm havin dificult to deal with rounding without loose precision. See my own answer how I solve the problem.

Comment: The reason you're getting this is due to the WGS84 Spheroid. Also, FYI, lat long at 18 decimal places is literally subatomic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols;
symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols( Locale.getDefault() );
symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');

df = new DecimalFormat("#.############", symbols);
this.longitude = Double.valueOf( df.format( longitude ) );
this.latitude = Double.valueOf( df.format(latitude ) );
```

Comment: This way I turn `1.107533167043945E-18` into `0.0` and keep decimal places of other numbers (`2.317684453562` for example )